# Are the bonuses from Silent Killer cumulative?

Tags: payday-2

Are the two bonuses from Basic and Aced cumulative, or does the Aced level list the total bonus damage?

[image]

With both levels, will I have +30% or + 45% damage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *think* doesn't stack.

> Silent Killer
>
> > Basic (4 pt): You deal more damage with all silencer weapons.
> >     Deal 15% more damage with silenced weapons
> >
> > Ace (8 pt): You deal even more damage and have a chance to pierce armor.
> >     Deal 30% more damage with silenced weapons. 15% chance to pierce armor **(does not stack. 27.75% with both skills)**

And

> c4ndlejack  [guide's author] 9 Sep 2013 @ 2 h 55
>
> > (...) Silent killer adds 30% aced.

Source : http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=169443444